# How to update UI in WPF application from thread?

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

I'm writing a client/server application and I'm trying to update UI from a thread that contains an infinite loop, in order to perform Socket.Receive. When I receive a packet on the socket, I have to update the UI and continue with the loop. The problem is that the thread can't manage the UI, so I tried to call BeginInvoke inside the thread, but the result was that UI froze. Is there a simple procedure that allows to call BeginInvoke inside a thread and returns the control to UI?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a blocking invoke to update UI on the main thread. This way, the thread will wait for the update to finish, and then continue. You were invoking in a non-blocking async way, which probably flooded the main thread and that's why it froze.

```
System.Windows.Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(delegate{
    // update UI
});
```

Comment: You can invoke from any thread anytime. Basically just copy-paste this code into your thread loop and update the UI inside the delegate. That's it.